# Segmentation error in fortran LAPACK routine

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, gfortran, lapack

I am trying to run a simple program with LAPACK library using fortran 95.  I am solving linear system of equations as: `Ax=B`

```
A = [4 -2 3]
    [1 3 -4]
    [3 1 2]

B=[ 1
   -7
   5]
```

`x` is solution vector

Solution is

```
x = [-1
     2
     3]
```

Here is the code. I am using two subroutines: [SGETRF](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/de/de2/sgetrf_8f.html) and [SGETRS](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d6/da0/sgetrs_8f.html). First function `SGETRF` computes LU decomposition of the matrix and second subroutine solves the system of equations.

```
program main
implicit none

integer :: i,j,info1,info2
integer :: neqn ! number of equations
real,dimension(3,3) :: coeff
real,dimension (3,1) :: lhs
real,dimension (3,1) :: ipiv

neqn=3

coeff = reshape( (/4,1,3,-2,3,1,3,-4,2/),(/3,3/))
lhs = reshape ( (/1,-7,5/),(/3,1/) )

call SGETRF (neqn,1,coeff,neqn,ipiv,infO1)
        if (info1==0) then
            call SGETRS ('N',neqn,1,coeff,neqn,ipiv,lhs,neqn,info2) !Error
        else
        end if

write (*,*) 'Answer: '
        do j=1,neqn,1
            write (*,100) lhs(j,1)
            100 format (F12.5,' ,')
        end do

        write (*,100) (lhs)

end program
```

As per LAPACK documentation SGETRF, in my case, `M=neqn=3, N=1, A=coeff, LDA=3`
I compiled the program as `gfortran main.f95 -o main -fcheck=all -llapack`
And I get the error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F758C3B3777
#1  0x7F758C3B3D7E
#2  0x7F758C00BD3F
#3  0x7F758CA2F3EF
#4  0x7F758C9BE8ED
#5  0x400AE0 in MAIN__ at main.f95:19
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Line 19 is `call SGETRS ('N',neqn,1,coeff,neqn,ipiv,lhs,neqn,info2)`
I do not understand why there is error. Any idea or comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is caused by the second parameter to `SGETRF`. This parameter is the second dimension of `coeff` and should thus be `3` or `neqn`.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Stefan's correct answer, here is a reworking of your code. I believe some potential for error is removed by programming carefully against the LAPACK spec (for example, the `ipiv` array should be rank-1 `Integer`) and by avoiding so many literal constants:

```
Program main
  Implicit None
  Integer, Parameter :: neqn = 3, nrhs = 1
  Integer :: info
  Real :: coeff(neqn, neqn)
  Real :: lhs(neqn, nrhs)
  Integer :: ipiv(neqn)
  coeff = reshape([4,1,3,-2,3,1,3,-4,2], shape(coeff))
  lhs = reshape([1,-7,5], shape(lhs))
  Call sgetrf(neqn, size(coeff,2), coeff, size(coeff,1), ipiv, info)
  If (info==0) Then
    Call sgetrs('N', neqn, size(lhs,2), coeff, size(coeff,1), ipiv, lhs, &
      size(lhs,1), info)
    If (info==0) Then
      Write (*, *) 'Answer: '
      Write (*, *)(lhs)
    End If
  End If
End Program
```